# Quick jump from component in Schematic to Layout in Eagle

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad

I always used the German software Target3001 to design my electronic boards, but recently switched to Eagle. There is one feature from Target3001 that seems to be missing in Eagle. I'm using version EAGLE 8.1.0 Premium.

**1. The feature in Target3001**

When I clicked on a component in the Schematic view, next switch to the Layout view, the corresponding component would be highlighted.

Just imagine how useful this is. I click in my schematic on `IC7`, then I switch to the layout view. First thing I see is `IC7` highlighted there! In just two mouseclicks I find it back :-)

**2. How I try doing it in Eagle**

In Eagle this is more time-consuming. First I need to look at the name of the component in the schematic view, eg. `IC7`. Next I switch to Layout view, then click Ctrl+F and type `IC7`. Then it gets highlighted.

Note: I have assigned to keyboard combination `Ctrl+F` to `run find.ulp`. If I wouldn't have done that, the procedure would be even more inefficient.

Please help me to do it more efficiently.

**3. The 'eye-button' doesn't work..**

Some people advised me to click on the 'eye-button', then click on the component in schematic view and finally switch to layout view. The corresponding component in layout view should get highlighted. Unfortunately, this doesn't happen in EAGLE 8.1.0 Premium.

Comment: I's called "cross-probing". Just click on the "eye" icon in both editors and it should work (IIRC... true for few years ago.. maybe there is no more eye icon there at all..)

Comment: Thank you @EugeneSh. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I just tried it. I'm using the latest version of Eagle: `EAGLE 8.1.0 Premium`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the "Show" command.  Its icon looks like an "eye".

Click on the Show button (the "eye"), then click on a part in the schematic. It should become highlighted.

Now look at the layout. The part should be highlighted as well.

This should also work in the other direction: from layout to schematic. You can use it with nets, too.

As Tom Carpenter said, you can also invoke this from the EAGLE command line, e.g. "show IC7".  This will highlight the part in both the schematic and the layout.

Comment: The command is called "show". You can use it from the eagle command line too (e.g. "show IC7").

Comment: Hi @bitsmack, thank you very much. Unfortunately, this doesn't function in `EAGLE 8.1.0 premium`. I just tried it :-(

Comment: @K.Mulier That's strange; I'm fairly certain it should. Do you have both the schematic window and the layout window open at the same time?

Comment: Yes, I do. Do you use the same Eagle version? Perhpas there is a bug in the newest version, not existing in previous ones.